# Use a changeset condition with if

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Can we use a changeset condition with if in Jenkins

```
 if (changeset "**/ml/docker/Dockerfile-dataproc-pp") {
    echo "Pushing all docker images with all tags to GCR"
  }
```

When I use the above way, it throws the error -

```
expecting ')', found '**/ml/docker/Dockerfile-dataproc-pp' @ line 196, column 39.
                       if (changeset "**/ml/docker/Dockerfile-dataproc-pp") {
                                     ^
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: You cant use changeset in scripted pipeline syntax, only in **when** directives of declarative pipelines.